# How do I force a page to postback when required textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm writing a website with asp.net and vb.net
I have a form which has textboxes with required attribute each.
The form doesn't get submitted until all inputs are filled in. But my problem is that I have a cancel button which clears texts from all input boxes in code behind.
I want to force a postback when the cancel button is clicked (even when some input boxes are empty).

I have no clue on what to do. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you did your validation. If you did it with asp.net then you can set the [CausesValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation?view=netframework-4.8) property to false. If it's an other type of validation, then you'll need to specify which one.

```
<asp:Button CausesValidation="False" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I used html required = "required" attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it out and it worked. Thanks a lot